# Combining sql inner and outer joins over multiple columns

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb

I am having problems with the syntax of how to join the following tables in a select statement in sql.
The relationship is as follows: Table **a** has an inner join to **b** and **d**. Table **b** also has an inner join to **c**. Table **e** has a left join to **a,b,c,d** using fields from **b** and **d**.

Here is the code. The important part is at the bottom. The rest is just fields from tables and calculated fields. It seems to almost work in that it retrives the data. However there is something not quite right as base is deleting a Broker_Commissions row when a Futures_Orders row is deleted.Bearing in mind there is not a delete cascade set on Futures_Orders with any other table.

```
SELECT "Futures_Orders"."Date"
    ,"Futures_Orders"."Symbol"
    ,"Futures_Orders"."Contract_Mth"
    ,"Futures_Orders"."Send_To_Broker"
    ,"Futures_Orders"."Order-Id"
    ,"Futures_Orders"."Broker"
    ,"Futures_Orders"."Order_Action"
    ,"Futures_Orders"."No_Contracts"
    ,"Futures_Orders"."Order_Price"
    ,"Futures_Orders"."Trade_Type"
    ,CASE "Futures_Orders"."Order_Action"
        WHEN 'b'
            THEN 's'
        ELSE 'b'
        END "If_Done_Action"
    ,"Futures_Orders"."If_Done_Price"
    ,"Futures_Orders"."No_Contracts" * (
        CASE "Contract_Details"."USIntRates"
            WHEN 'n'
                THEN ABS("Futures_Orders"."Order_Price" - "Futures_Orders"."If_Done_Price") / "Contract_Details"."MinTick"
            ELSE ABS(ABS(TRUNCATE (
                            "Futures_Orders"."Order_Price"
                            ,0
                            ) - TRUNCATE (
                            "Futures_Orders"."If_Done_Price"
                            ,0
                            )) * "Contract_Details"."MinTick" - CASE 
                        WHEN "Contract_Details"."Symbol" IN (
                                'FV'
                                ,'TU'
                                )
                            THEN 400
                        ELSE 200
                        END * ABS("Futures_Orders"."Order_Price" - TRUNCATE (
                            "Futures_Orders"."Order_Price"
                            ,0
                            ) - "Futures_Orders"."If_Done_Price" + TRUNCATE (
                            "Futures_Orders"."If_Done_Price"
                            ,0
                            )))
            END * "Contract_Details"."MinTickVal" / "FX_Rates"."Rate" + CASE 
            WHEN "Broker_Commissions"."Commission" IS NULL
                OR "Broker_Commissions"."Commission_AUD" + "Broker_Commissions"."Commission" = 0
                THEN "Broker"."Commission"
            ELSE "Broker_Commissions"."Commission_AUD" + "Broker_Commissions"."Commission" / "FX_Rates"."Rate"
            END * 2
        ) "Risk"
    ,"Futures_Orders"."Trade_Reason"
    ,"Contract_Details"."MinTick"
    ,"Contract_Details"."MinTickVal"
    ,"Contract_Details"."Symbol"
    ,"Contract_Details"."Currency"
    ,"FX_Rates"."Code"
    ,"Broker"."Broker"
    ,"Broker_Commissions"."Symbol"
    ,"Broker_Commissions"."Broker"
    ,"Broker_Commissions"."ID"
FROM "Futures_Orders"
    ,"Contract_Details"
    ,"Broker"
    ,"FX_Rates"
LEFT JOIN "Broker_Commissions" ON "Broker_Commissions"."Broker" = "Broker"."Broker"
    AND "Broker_Commissions"."Symbol" = "Contract_Details"."Symbol"
WHERE "Contract_Details"."Symbol" = "Futures_Orders"."Symbol"
    AND "Broker"."Broker" = "Futures_Orders"."Broker"
    AND "FX_Rates"."Code" = "Contract_Details"."Currency"
```

Comment: Can you provide sample table data and your expected output? Or even better - a jsFiddle and expected output.

Comment: Tables don't have "inner" or "outer" relationships to other tables.  Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are doing.  Also, a query that you have tried with an explanation of why it doesn't work would provide insight into your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something similar to this.

`<field>` is different for each relationship but you didnt provide that

```
 SELECT 
 FROM a
 INNER JOIN b
         ON a.<field> = b.<field>
 INNER JOIN d
         ON a.<field> = d.<field>
 INNER JOIN c
         ON b.<field> = c.<field>
 LEFT JOIN e
         ON e.<field> = b.<field>
        AND e.<field> = d.<field>
```

Comment: This code works fine when adding, retrieving and modifying rows. However when I attempt to delete a row I get the following error message: Error deleting the specified records.   invalid argumnent in JDBC call: parameter index out of range: 1.  Also I notice that base changes the join code to the following:

Comment: You cannot delete records from multiple joined tables at the same time. Write separate delete statements for each table.

Comment: Libreoffice Base, which is the front end I am using, is doing the adding, deleting and modifying of rows. All I do is write the query and it does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the columns you want to joined are named the same in both tables (and there is no repetition causing ambiguity), we can use NATURAL to simplify the syntax.

```
d NATURAL LEFT JOIN (a NATURAL JOIN (b NATURAL JOIN c) NATURAL JOIN d)
```

You can replace `NATURAL ... JOIN X` with `JOIN X ON (COLA = COLB)` syntax

Your actual example is different and can be written this way:

```
FROM "Futures_Orders" NATURAL JOIN "Contract_Details"
 NATURAL JOIN "Broker"
 INNER JOIN "FX_Rates" ON ("FX_Rates"."Code" = "Contract_Details"."Currency")
 NATURAL LEFT JOIN "Broker_Commissions"
```

If you use NATURAL join, the columns of the same name must be referenced in the query without their table name.

You mention Base (OpenOffice or LibreOffice), which has it's own preprocessor and syntax differences which can modify the query, sometimes incorrectly.

Comment: first time i see this syntaxis. doesnt need parenthesis for `((b NATURAL JOIN c) NATURAL JOIN d))` ?

Comment: You can remove the parentheses around (b Natural JOIN c).